# Using for loop in javascript for 50k time without hanging of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have to run a loop for 50,000 times, but it is hanging browser. what could be the best way to do it.

sample :

```
for(var i=0;i<50000;i++)
{
// Here I am calculating 50 different values.
}
```

I can't use php because values are displayed directly in html page.

what I can do for it?

thanks

Comment: If you're doing something really data-intensive but you don't want to block the browser process, you might look into doing that work in a Service Worker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Comment: …what are you doing in the loop? An empty `for()` loop of that sort runs essentially instantly; it won't hang the browser.

Comment: If you don't explain what you're doing, or show code that approximates your real task, we can't realistically offer any useful advice for reducing the workload or minimising its effect on the browser.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the things you are calculating for in the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [webworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). [Here](https://github.com/mattslocum/ng-webworker) is a package that might simplify things for you.